# Set up Jest with webpack and react-css-modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I am trying to set up jest with webpack and react-css-modules in this repo: [react-webpack-lab](https://github.com/SimoNonnis/react-webpack-lab). 
When I run `yarn test` I got this error:

[image]

anyone is able to understand why I get this error?